# Disabling Rstudio Dataframe preview on code completion

Tags: rstudio

I updated to latest rstudio version and now whenever i try to hover over a dataframe global env in code completion it previews it. I want to disable this feature. How can i do it?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try `options(rstudio.help.showDataPreview = FALSE)`.

Source: https://github.com/rstudio/rstudio/issues/13286#issuecomment-1607517508